# Черный экран после установки видеодрайвера amd в windows 10

Tags: windows-10

Доброго времени, стэковерйлоучане, столкнулся  со следующей проблемой, решил заменить свою уже заюзанную ось на новую, была windows 10x64 какой-то сборки, уже не помню, никаких нареканий, в плане работы видеокарты, не было. Решил скачать пробную версию с оф сайта, переустановил, вроде все работало, но как только произошла автоматическая загрузка/установка видеодрайвера - все в начале зависло и через некоторое время(до минуты) экран погас, даже после нескольких перезагрузок- экрантзагрузкиивиндоус есть, в дальше верный экран.Я пытался проверить зажимая и многократно нажимая на клавишу shift, нажимал win+r вводил неправильную команду пытаясь вызвать звуковой сигнал - ничего, пытался так же ( в слепую) через командную строку перезагрузится (shutdown /r), переустанавливал винду, отключал автоматические обновления, скачивал и устанавливал драйвера, отключал так же быструю загрузку оси, ничего не помогло. Удостоверился в том что проблема именно в видеодрайвере следующим способом: загружался в безопасном режиме и через диспетчер устройств отключал свою видеоадаптер.
Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с похожей проблемой и знает её решение ?
Видеокарта: ATI HD 5xxx

Comment: Ну, если проблема гарантировано с видеодрайвером, попробуйте загрузить драйвер на автоматически, а вручную, с сайта производителя. И поставить его.

Comment: @VladD я так делал, качал вручную и устанавливал, кроме этого использовал autodetect с сайта amd скачивал и устанавливал - ничего, сейчас попробую скачать какую-нибудь сборку с рутрекера и на ней проверю. Спасибо за ваш комментарий.

Comment: А если временно заменить видеокарту?

Comment: Ну и может у вас в BIOS не отключена встроенная видеокарта, и это мешает. Проверьте.

Comment: @VladD меняю видеокарту не физически, отключая действующую не работающую. Все нормально, только там используется Microsoft basic video driver и разрешение 1000х600. Ок, у меня уже заканчивается установка в очередной раз:( в биосе  чуть позже проверю.

Comment: А кстати, имеет смысл указать в вопросе модель вашей видеокарты. Возможно, по ней выгуглится что-то интересное.

Comment: @VladD ati hd 5xxx( уже все перепробовал - ничего (

Comment: очень большое подозрение что винда испорчена. откуда ты брал дистрибутив? он официальный?

Comment: @stas0k да, скачал с офф сайта 90-дневную пробную версию.

Comment: @VladD после многочисленных установок/переустановок как драйверов так и windows, решил проверить работоспособность на windows 7, единственная возникшая проблема после установки драйвера на семерку - экран был без подсветки и никаких зависаний системы и черного экрана, а в семерке проблема решается так [ссылка на решение](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=m5xK0c-3LhE)  на десятке может и проверю когда -нибудь, работать нужно, буду на семерке пока.

Comment: @VladimirKhodakovskey: Здорово! Может быть, распишите эту инструкцию в виде ответа? Пусть даже частичного, для Windows 7. Было бы круто для следующих поколений.

Comment: @VladD так и сделаю, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Устав от многочисленных установок и переустановок,как драйверов, так и самой операционнй системы, решил проверить работоспособность драйвера на какой-нибудь боле старой версии виндоус, выбрал Windows 7 SP1 X 64, после установки драйвера возникла следющая проблема - была отключена подсветка в экране, решается это следующим образом:
Можно заргузиться в безопасном режиме или же подсвечивать экран фонариком,

1)жмем **Win + R** и вводим **regedit**;

2)Идем в  **[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class{4D36E968-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0000]**

3)Кликаем по пустому месту и создаем два **DWORD(32-bit) value** со следующими именами **KMD_EnableBrightnesslf2** и **KMD_EnableBrightnessInterface2**;

4)Кликаем дважды по каждому созданному файлу и в поле **Data Value** пишем **1**;

5)Перезагружаемся;

По всей видимости проблема кроится где-то в смой windows 10,  если найду причину - дополню свой ответ.

Comment: @RifmaMan не за что, рад что мое решение помогло :) успехов!